# Django Rest doesen't declate explicit

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm installing django rest framework and when I add rest-framework in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, I'm receiving error like:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest-framework'

Traceback (most recent call last):

RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Any ideas what is that?

Comment: Show us `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you removed the content types from the installed apps. In your settings.py add:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
]
```